# FullCalendar display +N more but not the title

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I am using FullCalendar3.5.1 Everything working correctly except when there are more than one event for the day (they comes dynamically through JSON), it just display +N more.The examples I have seen it should display atleast one event title and then say +(N-1) more.
But for me, even if there are 2 events it display none and say +2 more
[image]

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultDate: new Date(),
        editable: true,
        eventBackgroundColor: '#3672BB',
        eventLimit: {               
            'default': false // display all events for other views
        },
        eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
            if (calEvent.isSvey){
                LoadApptPage(calEvent.eventID,'2');
                }
            else{
                LoadApptPage(calEvent.eventID,'1');
            }
        },
        events: [{"aID":"62241-008","start":"10\/11\/2017","eventID":9608,"isSvey":1,"autoschld":0,"missed":0,"title":"62241-008 - "},{"aID":"162215-003","start":"10\/11\/2017","eventID":9606,"isSvey":1,"autoschld":0,"missed":0,"title":"162215-003 - Construction LLC"},{"aID":162738,"start":"10\/24\/2017","eventID":9607,"isSvey":1,"autoschld":1,"missed":0,"title":"162738 - "}],
        eventRender: function(event, element) {
            //element.find(".fc-title").remove();
            element.find(".fc-time").remove();
            var pbSveyFlag = event.isSvey ? 2 : 1;
            //var new_description =   '<a style="color:#FFF;font-Weight:bold;" href="javascript:LoadApptPage(' + event.eventID +',' + pbSveyFlag +')">' 
            //  + event.title + '</a><br/><br/> +'
            var new_description = 
                 '<br/><a style="color:#FFF;font-Weight:bold;" href="javascript:LoadFurPage(' + '&#39;' + event.aID + '&#39;' +',' + '&#39;'+pbSveyFlag +'&#39;' +')">'
                + '<strong>View: </strong>'  + '</a>' + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'
                + generateLink(event.autoschld,event.missed,event.eventID,event.aID)

            ;
            element.append(new_description);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Show us your  code, and a minimal set of event data so we can try to help.  [How to create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Code has been added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `eventLimit` syntax is incorrect.  You only need to specify `false`, like so:

```
eventLimit: false,
```

In fact [the default is false](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/eventLimit/), so you can simply leave this out all together and it will work the same.

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6wqmw7Lv/).  I had to remove your reference to `generateLink()`, it is not relevant to the current problem.  I also removed your `eventClick` callback as it is not relevant to the current problem.

Side note - your `start` values do not need the slashes escaped.  Also, they are not Moment-ish values ([as described in the docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/), so generate warnings on the console.  The docs link to the ISO8601 Wikipedia page which shows several examples of suitable date formats.  If you don't have times, the simplest would be just to use YYYY-MM-DD:

```
"start":"2017-10-11",
```